# Multiple rows deleting in jtable with the same value

Tags: java, swing, jtable

im making a java swing project , ive connected to my database and calling all the values into a JTable , in my frame when you click on a row in the Jtable and click the delete button then the value is deleted , but i have a bug because if you try to delete a value(example if u delete the number 1) and there is another same value(number 1) in the jtable then both of them will delete

I think the problem is in this code

```
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            try {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                String Description = (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1)).toString();

                String query = "select * from PostNotice where Description='" + Description + "'";
                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);

                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    textArea.setText(rs.getString("Description"));
                }

                pst.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This is for the delete

```
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


             String query = "Delete from PostNotice where Description =?";
            try {

                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1, textArea.getText());
                pst.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Post Deleted");

                pst.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            textArea.setText("");
            textArea.requestFocus();
            refreshtable();
        }

    });
```

Comment: where is delete query? or delete logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have to keep reference to ID (or another primary key) and delete record by the primary key value.

For you code it means e.g. `Long id` class' field and store the id from DB to the field

```
textArea.setText(rs.getString("Description"));
id=rs.getLong("id");
```

Then you can use the `id` to delete

```
String query = "Delete from PostNotice where id=?";
...
pst.setLong(1, id);
```